# How to import a shadow-cljs project into another shadow-cljs project with a different configuration

Tags: webpack, clojurescript, reagent, shadow-cljs, clojurescript-javascript-interop

I currently have 2 shadow-cljs projects with 2 different ways to manage their [dependencies to npm libraries](https://shadow-cljs.github.io/docs/UsersGuide.html#js-provider).

One uses the default shadow-cljs.edn configuration `:js-options {:js-provider :shadow}`, we will call it **project A**.

The other, we will call it **project B**, uses the external configuration with the use of webpack inside the shadow-cljs.edn file  `:js-options {:js-provider :external :external-index "target/index.js"}` as described in the following article [How about webpack now?](https://code.thheller.com/blog/shadow-cljs/2020/05/08/how-about-webpack-now.html#option-2-js-provider-external:)

Locally I can run these **project A** and **project B** independently without errors.

However, I would now like to import **project A** into **project B**, and use the method `my-function` from project_A.core.

```
(ns project_A.core)

(defn ^:export my-function  [] ...)
```

I tried to release **project** A by specifying the `:target` field of the shadow-cljs.edn file to the value `:npm-module`.

***Project A > shadow-cljs.edn :***

```
{
[...]
 :builds   {:app {:target           :npm-module
                  :output-dir       "release/"
                  :entries          [project_A.core]
                  :js-options       {:js-provider :external :external-index "target/index.js"}}}
[...]
}}
```

Then I install it in **project B** i did a `npm install path/to/project_A`, as for a classic npm package and to use it the same way as the others.

I tried to add the local dependency like this:

***Project B > package.json :***

```
{
  "scripts": {[...]},
  "devDependencies": {[...]},
  "dependencies": {
    [...]
    "project_A": "file:path/to/project_A",
    [...]
  },
  "name": "projet B",
}
```

And I try to import the package inside the ns require field. However project B does not compile.

Is there a clean way to import a project into the other one while taking into account their different configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is incorrect. You never include the build output of one CLJS library/project in another. You always include the sources directly instead, and then build the proper final output only where you are going to use it. You cannot include CLJS libraries via `npm` `package.json`, neither should you want to.

So, for the purpose of this explanation the build config in A is entirely irrelevant. It doesn't need to be built, we only want access to the sources.

In B you have a couple options of using it. Say you have everything in `~/code/project-a` and `~/code/project-b`.

In `~/code/project-b/shadow-cljs.edn` you can specify `:source-paths ["src/main" "../project-a/src/main"]`. This will make all sources from A directly accessible when building B. It does however require manually transferring the `:dependencies` from A to B.

Another option is using a local install (or maven install), but for this you'll need `lein` or `deps.edn` to build the `.jar`. `shadow-cljs` itself does not support publishing "libraries".

Another option is using the [clojure tools](https://clojure.org/guides/deps_and_cli) `deps.edn` with `:local/root`.

```clj
;; ~/code/project-a/deps.edn

{:paths ["src/main"]
 :deps {...}
 :aliases
 {:dev {:extra-deps {thheller/shadow-cljs {:mvn/version "2.22.8"}}}}}

;; ~/code/project-b/deps.edn

{:paths ["src/main"]
 :deps {my.company/project-a {:local/root "../project-a"}}
 :aliases
 {:dev {:extra-deps {thheller/shadow-cljs {:mvn/version "2.22.8"}}}}}

;; ~/code/project-b/shadow-cljs.edn

{:deps {:aliases [:dev]}
 :builds ...}
```

Also make sure you actually need to split projects in the first place. It is perfectly fine and even encouraged to build mutiple outputs out of one project. So, often I see people splitting things because of "best practices". Which often isn't necessary and just makes things complicated for no good reason. IMHO, YMMV. If you really must, `deps.edn` is the most flexible option.

As far as `npm` dependencies are concerned you `project-a` can express them via a `deps.cljs` file on the classpath. So, with the above config `~/code/project-a/src/main/deps.cljs` with `{:npm-deps {"the-dep" "the-version"}}`. These must be manually added, as the `package.json` is not "inherited". When you start `shadow-cljs` in B it'll pick those `:npm-deps` and transfer them to the `package.json` in B. You then build everything as usual in B.

Comment: I had already tried the solution using the clojure tools `deps.edn` with `:local/root`. However when I added the require in a file of my B project : 

`(ns project-b.core (:require [project-a.core :as pjt-a]))`

I got an error message saying: 

`The required JS dependency "XXX" is not available, it was required by "project-a/core.cljs".`
I use webpack to manage my libraries in **project A** and not in **project B** because the _XXX_ library is not compatible with the normal package management of shadow-cljs.

I was at this point of blocking, that's why I tried to use `npm-module`.

Comment: The package management of **project A** is related to this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75831526/walletconnect-v2-0-library-integration-issues-with-shadow-cljs

Comment: I expanded the answer to mention `:npm-deps`. You must use `webpack` in B as well, if you wish to use the incompatible packages.